# Обособление деепричастных и т. п. оборотов, заканчивающих одну часть сложного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая после "топором" в предложении: "Были люди, которые могли строить прекрасные дома, управляясь одним топором, — почему бы не прорубить двери в царство божие на земле, вооружившись дубиной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **В качестве вступления к теме**

Я тоже не раз встречала **отсутствие запятых** в подобных конструкциях, да и вообще специально отслеживаю эту тему.

**Чем она интересна?** Вроде бы существует правило, призывающее нас ставить знаки препинания "независимо". Но что выражает это правило, **в чем его глубинный смысл?** Я не уверена, что кто-нибудь ответит. И в то же время существует принцип: знаки препинания должны помогать **правильно читать и понимать текст.**
В этом плане независимая запятая ничему не способствует, а правило выглядит формально.

В то же время эту запятую **можно нагрузить смыслом, заставить работать**. Если приглядеться к современным текстам, то в одной и той же книге можно увидеть примеры с разным оформлением: вот обособленный оборот закрыт запятой, а вот здесь – нет.

Конечно, многим людям знаки препинания представляются чисто **оформительскими знаками.** Такая точка зрения удобна, так как не требует особых знаний. Но простое может быть как совершенным, так и примитивным. Потенциальные возможности русской пунктуации таковы, что она **способна выразить** самые тонкие смысловые оттенки. Поэтому очень не хватает **новой редакции** правил, где были бы отражены эти возможности.

А вот правила Розенталя  имеют **одну редакцию**, которая предлагается как школьникам для написания сочинений, так и авторам художественных произведений, в которых используется **много нестандартной грамматики.** А правила – одни и те же! А нужно два уровня: простой и расширенный.

**2) Ответ на вопрос**

*А, может быть, у этого эксперимента другая цель. Будучи столь далеки от главного в нас, столь несовершенны, столь невежественны по отношению к этому главному, вымучим ли мы наконец этот выход к законам тонкой энергии, их познание и роспись, поставим ли мы этот учебник себе на службу? **Были люди, которые могли строить прекрасные дома, управляясь одним топорОм — почему бы не прорубить двери в царство божие на земле, вооружившись дубИной?***

В данном случае **деепричастный оборот нежелательно закрывать запятой**, так как он тесно примыкает к придаточному  и читается с ним в одну фразу, без паузы.  Разделительное тире выражает **взаимообусловленные отношения** между частями сложного предложения, а закрывающая запятая этому препятствует.

В тексте постановка запятой соответствует формальному правилу. Пока еще это правило является действующим, его никто не отменял,  но на практике можно видеть, что смысловая постановка запятой применяется достаточно часто.

Comment: Sharon, большое спасибо за такой подробный комментарий! Конечно, универсальность Розенталя в данном случае не может отразить всей тонкости смыслов.

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужна, потому что "в большинстве случаев каждый из этих знаков препинания ставится на собственном основании".

Похожий пример, вопрос 299833 на "Грамоте":

> Правило таково. При встрече внутри предложения запятой и тире сначала
>   ставится запятая, а после нее тире. То есть тире не поглощает запятую.
>   В справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя это глава "[Сочетание знаков препинания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175)".
>
> Верно: Вы можете переписываться в **беседах, не отрываясь от разговора, —** достаточно просто свернуть звонок. Пересчитали
>   комментарии с учетом только уникальных пользователей, которые
>   оставляют меньше 11 комментариев в сутки (чтобы исключить ботов), —
>   всё равно рост от года к году.

Comment: Homocomputeris, большое спасибо! Я всегда обособляла такие структурные единицы и задала вопрос, потому что во многих случаях встречала отсутствие запятых перед тире в конструкциях, подобных Вами приведённым.